# За что отвечают мета тег csrf-param и csrf-token?

Tags: html, http, теги

Подскажите, за что отвечают мета тег csrf-param и csrf-token, не могу найти нигде их описания.

Comment: Подозреваю этих тегов нет ни в каком стандарте. А судя по названию они для защиты от CSRF атаки.

Answer (score 3):

CodeIgniter:

> Межсайтовая подделка запросов
> (Cross-site request forgery, CSRF)
>
> Вы можете включить защиту CSRF, открыв
> ваш application/config/config.php и
> установив в нем:
>
> `$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;`
>
> Если вы используете помощник форм,
> функция form_open() автоматически
> будет добавлять скрытое поле CSRF в
> ваши формы.

Answer (score 2):

[CSRF – атаки. (Cross-Site Request Forgery)](http://www.inattack.ru/article/csrf---ataki-cross-site-request-forgery/552.html#.UKsvLuPZ8zE)

> CSRF расшифровывается как “Cross-Site Request Forgery” (Межсайтовая подделка запроса). Данный тип атак направлен на имитирование запроса пользователя к стороннему сайту. Эта уязвимость достаточно широко распространена из за особенностей архитектуры большинства веб-приложений. А именно из-за того, что многие веб-приложения не чётко определяют - действительно ли запрос сформирован настоящим пользователем.